# Filtrar o primeiro resultado da função explode do PHP e apresentar em uma estrutura

Tags: php

Como posso eliminar o primeiro resultado do explode. Convertendo em *array*, `$separa[0];` consigo filtrar, mais to com dificuldade de eliminar ele da estrutura foreach.

Exemplo:

```
$separa = explode(",", $row['referencia']);  

$separa[0]; //obtenho o primeiro resultado

foreach($separa as $ref ) : 

      echo$ref; //imprimir sem o $separa[0]; (primeiro resultado)
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente:

```
unset($separa[0]);
```

E faça o foreach

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado Mastria.